# Единственное или множественное число? (2)

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: улучшить состояние сердечно-сосудистой, дыхательной, пищеварительной систем (или системы?)

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Улучшить состояние сердечно-сосудистой, дыхательной, пищеварительной систем.

Их же много

Comment: Я думала,что системы, так как это слова терминологического характера, типа глаголы настоящего, прошедшего и будущего времени, не говорим же мы времен.

Comment: Время - оно как бы одно, и у него есть разные свойства: будущее, настоящее, позапрошлое... А системы именно разные.

Comment: Дело не в терминологическом характере. В вашем примере мн.ч. зависит от глагола ''улучшить". Т.е.согласование по типу  управление. Улучшить состояние чего? - систем, а системы.

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, мы говорим и _система времён_ (английского глагола). Странно всё это...

Comment: Стопкран, что вас так удивляет? Система - чего? - времен.